# SAPUI5 IconTabBar get selection before and after user interaction

Tags: javascript, xml, events, controls, sapui5

I have a XML View with a SAPUI5 `<IconTabBar>`which is connected to an event handler method.
It looks like that:

```
<IconTabBar id="ITB1" select="onSelect">
  <items>
    <IconTabFilter id="ITF1" text="{i18n>textITF1}" icon="sap-icon://area-chart"/>
    <IconTabFilter id="ITF2" text="{i18n>textITF2}" icon="sap-icon://area-chart"/>
    <IconTabFilter id="ITF3" text="{i18n>textITF3}" icon="sap-icon://area-chart"/>
  </items>
</IconTabBar>
```

Now I want to check in the function

```
onSelect
```

what was selected before the user "click" and after the user "click".
F.ex. first `ITF1` was selected and now `ITF2` is selected. Based on the last selected `IconTabFilter` I want to do a different handling.

My problem is that in the `onSelect` function the selected item is already updated and so I do not know what was selected before the user interaction.

Is there a way to get the selected item before it is changed in the `IconTabBar` control?

With best regards
ChristianR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no parameter in the event, which tells you the previous state. You could store it yourself

```
_previousIFT: 'IFT1',
 onSelect: function(oEvent) {
      var oPrevIFT = this.getView().byId(this._previousIFT);
     // do something with oPrevIFT and new IFT from event
      // store the Id of the new IFT from event into this._previousIFT
 }
```